# How to print dsyev (or LAPACK in general) function progress?

Tags: c, performance, concurrency, parallel-processing, intel-mkl

I am using `dsyev` with `Intel MKL` in C.

I am diagonalizing a `20_000 x 20_000` real symmetric matrix of `double`s.

**I want to know how much time is left from the dsyev call, or roughly where it is.**

I compile the source .c code using the Intel Link Line advisor.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, LAPACK methods are not designed to do that.

You can create a performance model on the target machine and analyse the complexity of the function to predict the computational time taken by the function (approximate time). Alternatively you can reimplement the function using BLAS building block (not very simple).